# Node.js - Promise not resolving within loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Good day all,

I'm working on extracting some data out of PipeDrive's API using Axios for Node.js. The way that PipeDrive developed their API pagination is a bit different. Here is how their pagination indicator looks:

```
    "additional_data": {
    "pagination": {
        "start": 0,
        "limit": 100,
        "more_items_in_collection": true,
        "next_start": 100
    }
}
```

I need to interate through all pages to extract the data, and my code has successfully done that, but I cannot get my promise to resolve for some reason.

My logic in the code is as follows:

```
if(more_items_in_collection){Add current page's data then re-run the same function with the next_start as a parameter}
else{Add current page's data then RESOLVE the promise to complete the function}
```

But this resolution never happens, even though my code works (strange).

Gurus, can you please take a look at my code and let me know why you think it won't resolve (`function().then((result) => {OUTPUT})` never returns happens)?

Thanks as always!

```
 const queryPipeDrive = (start) =>{
 // Query is a full then-able Async function
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // API CALL
     axios({
         method: 'GET', 
         url: pipeDriveURI, 
         params: {
             api_token: apiKey, 
             start: start
         }
     })
     // THEN DO THIS
     .then((response) => {
         // IF there are more items in collection on additional pages, iterate through the pages
         if(response.data.additional_data.pagination.more_items_in_collection){
             // Add all deals on page to the container
             for (const deal of response.data.data) {
                 db.get('deals').push(deal) // Push deal data to the StormDB File
             }
             
             console.log(chalk.cyan(`${response.data.additional_data.pagination.next_start}`))
             // Function loop created. We will loop UNTIL the 'more_items_in_collection' prop is false, then we'll resolve the promise. 
             queryPipeDrive(response.data.additional_data.pagination.next_start)

         }else{
             // Add all deals on this page to the reponse container
             for (const deal of response.data.data) {
                 db.get('deals').push(deal)
             }
             db.save() // Save changes to temp DB
             resolve(response.data.data) // Resolve Promise with the data from the successful call
         }
     })
     .catch((err) => {
         console.log(chalk.red(err))
         reject(err)
     })
 })
```

}

Comment: `queryPipeDrive(`  -> `return queryPipeDrive(`

Comment: @Keith that's definitely on the right track, but returning the promise won't be enough, since they've wrapped this code in an extra promise

Comment: @NicholasTower  Yeah, just went to make a coffee, while I was gone remembered he had also used a promise constructor and was about to update.

Comment: you need to read [_"What is the explicit Promise construction anti-pattern and how do I avoid it?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: @Mulan, just read this and it makes total sense. I did learn the return new Promise route but now that I understand the concept, returning an actual promise instead of wrapping everything up in one make so much MORE sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your more_items_in_collection case never resolves the promise. It just creates a new one, then does nothing with it.

Additionally, you're making your code more complicated than it needs to be by using `new Promise`. Axios already returns a promise, so there's no need to explicitly create a new one. Calling `.then` will create a new promise automatically, which resolves to whatever value you return in the callback.

```
const queryPipeDrive = (start) => {
  // API CALL
  return axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: pipeDriveURI,
    params: {
      api_token: apiKey,
      start: start,
    },
  })
    // THEN DO THIS
    .then((response) => {
      // IF there are more items in collection on additional pages, iterate through the pages
      if (response.data.additional_data.pagination.more_items_in_collection) {
        // Add all deals on page to the container
        for (const deal of response.data.data) {
          db.get("deals").push(deal); // Push deal data to the StormDB File
        }

        console.log(
          chalk.cyan(`${response.data.additional_data.pagination.next_start}`)
        );
        // Function loop created. We will loop UNTIL the 'more_items_in_collection' prop is false, then we'll resolve the promise.
        return queryPipeDrive(
          response.data.additional_data.pagination.next_start
        );
      } else {
        // Add all deals on this page to the reponse container
        for (const deal of response.data.data) {
          db.get("deals").push(deal);
        }
        db.save(); // Save changes to temp DB
        return response.data.data;
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(chalk.red(err));
      throw err;
    });
};
```

Comment: Wow, this makes so much sense now! I just need to understand one thing, and hopefully you can help me wrap my head around it: I need this function to be Then-able so I can run more code ONCE this function is completed successfully. Is that possible without wrapping the entire function within a promise?

Comment: It *is* thenable. `axios` returns a promise, and calling `.then` or `.catch` on a promise also returns a promise. You just need to return the promise, which i did on line 2 of my example.

Comment: You are a literal genius! Thanks so much! This works beautifully! It Really helped my understanding of Promises!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the accepted answer.

Would you consider using this async function in await? In this way, you call the `main()`.

```js
const main = async start => {
  const res = await queryPipeDrive(start);
  if (res.isMoreItems === true) {
    await main(res.nextStart);
  }
};

async function queryPipeDrive(start) {
  const response = await axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: pipeDriveURI,
    params: {
      api_token: apiKey,
      start: start,
    },
  });

  for (const deal of response.data.data) {
    db.get("deals").push(deal);
  }

  if (response.data.additional_data.pagination.more_items_in_collection) {
    console.log(
      chalk.cyan(`${response.data.additional_data.pagination.next_start}`)
    );
    return {
      isMoreItems: true,
      nextStart: response.data.additional_data.pagination.next_start,
    };
  } else {
    db.save(); // Save changes to temp DB
    return {
      isMoreItems: false,
    };
  }
}
```